# cURL for UTF-8 Requests. it always goes like �abe when it's supposed to be çabe

Tags: c++, curl, libcurl

Well I'm using libcurl in C++ on Visual Studio 2008 and Windows 7 Professional 32-bit to send a request with UTF-8 characters but the problem is that I get that encoding error.
`�abe` instead of `çabe`.

and one thing I notice while I was testing in my localhost server, it's first I receive in a PHP server like this `echo $_POST['post'];` and it comes `�abe` but if I encode it, it comes correct: `echo utf8_encode($_POST['post']);` it comes `çabe` which is I want.

but the thing is that I don't have control over the server that receives the data, I would like to send it already encoded with UTF-8.

how could I do that?

here is my post part

```
struct curl_httppost *formpost=NULL;
struct curl_httppost *lastptr=NULL;
std::string post = "çabe";
url_formadd(&formpost,
      &lastptr,
      CURLFORM_COPYNAME, "post",
      CURLFORM_COPYCONTENTS, post.c_str(),
      CURLFORM_END);
```

**@edit**

According to DietrichEpp, to see if I have UTF-8 on, I can simply test the length of a different character in example "ç"
so I tried `printf("%d\n", (int) strlen("ç"));` --
and it should print out 2 or 3 for UTF-8, or 1 for something else.

and it did printed out 1, so that may be the reason, how can I fix this ?

I want to set it to be UTF-8 or at least be able to put a function to set it to be utf8 when using in the post field of the cURL.

Comment: I suspect it's a matter of setting a header like `Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8`.  However, you are at the mercy of the server, and it is possible that the server ignores you and there is nothing you can do about it.

Comment: it's not only this even if you put on Get like myaddress.php?param=çaça it gives this erros, and the server does handle it, it's a famous email website.

Comment: URLs are not encoded in utf8.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding

Comment: @HansPassant: Well, Unicode characters are encoded in UTF-8 first and then the resulting *octets* are percent-encoded.  Usually.  We can use IRIs now instead of URIs http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internationalized_Resource_Identifier

Comment: Grego, try dumping `"çabe"` as hex to stdout to see if the string literal is correct UTF-8.  There are notable compilers (MSVC) that will "helpfully" convert UTF-8 to other encodings for you.  Then check to see if the URL is correct in the request, you can sniff with netcat or Wireshark or something to see if the URL correctly contains `%C3%A7a%C3%A7a` for `çaça`.

Comment: If you use `"%s"`, then the resulting characters will be interpreted by your terminal and I don't know if your terminal is set up to use UTF-8 or what.  Try `printf("%d\n", (int) strlen("ç"))` -- it should print out 2 or 3 for UTF-8, or 1 for something else.

Comment: hmm thanks for answering @DietrichEpp I just said that as an example, but the problem is really on the post values :/ I don't know if I'm doing as hex, I'm not sure, but I did like this: printf("%s","çabe"); and the result shows a weird character instead of the "ç", how could I fix that encoding problem in the post values ? :/

Comment: @DietrichEpp it printed out 1 , so I must assume its not utf-8, what's the next step to fix this? btw I'm using windows

Comment: I think you just found your biggest problem. Unfortunately, it's hard to fix.

Comment: It doesn't have to be in the complete code, if I could do something like call_function_to_utf8("çabe"); to return the utf8 encoded code. this would probably fix the cURL post error, does that make it simpler ?

Comment: Presentation issue? The square `�` is a usual symbol that is used whenever a glyph isn't available in a font.

Comment: What compiler are you using under which OS? What is the encoding of the source file?

Comment: STATUS_ACCESS_DENIED, It appears normally in the VS 2008 source editor, the problem is when we post the data and I'm using Visual Studio 2008 under Windows 7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to send UTF-8 encoded data you *have to* encode it in UTF-8. For example “ç” encoded in UTF-8 can portabily be spelled `\xC3\xA7` as in

```
std::string post = "\xC3\xA7abe";
```

Visual Studio 2008 should be able to automatically [save file in UTF-8](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w11571b4%28v=vs.90%29.aspx), saving you the trouble of doing this encoding yourself. If you are stuck working in ISO 8859-1, this *specific transcoding* to UTF-8 can easily be achieved with (optimization left as an exercice):

```
std::string utf8_from_iso8859_1(std::string str)
{
  std::string res;
  for (std::string::iterator i = str.begin(); i < str.end(); i++) {
    if (0 <= *i && *i < 0x80)
      res += *i;
    else {
      res += 0xC0 | ((*i >> 6) & 0x03);
      res += 0x80 | (*i & 0x3F);
    }
  }
  return res;
}
```

and then use

```
std::string post = "çabe";
std::string encoded = utf8_from_iso8859_1(post);
url_formadd(&formpost,
  &lastptr,
  CURLFORM_COPYNAME, "post",
  CURLFORM_COPYCONTENTS, encoded.c_str(),
  CURLFORM_END);
```

Transcoding from other encodings will require a specific mapping and your best bet will be to use a specialized library like [libiconv](http://www.gnu.org/software/libiconv/)

Comment: In C++11 this can be accomplished with `u8"çabe"`. (Or by ensuring proper compiler configuration, but that's not really portable.) Passing a string literal to `utf8_from_iso8859_1` is just as dangerous as using a string literal directly… either way makes an assumption about the execution character set.

Comment: @Potatoswatter Right, I explicitely said “Apparently you are working in ISO 8859-1. In this specific case […]” before describing the transcoding trick. It *does* assume ISO 8859-1 source encoding.

I am not familiar with C++11 but my understanding is that even `u8` will *not* do the transcoding from foreign encodings to UTF-8. It *requires* that the source program already is UTF-8 encoded.

Comment: Yeah, the answer isn't wrong, I was just mentioning that this fix is equally platform-specific. No, `u8` stands for UTF-8 and a compiler that accepts an 8859-1 source program must transcode it. The standard is specific about the output and purposely makes the specification independent of the source coding.

Comment: Forgive me for my ignorance, or maybe I'm missing something, but the question is tagged as C, so what is the `std::string` doing here?

Comment: @EitanT I read the question and I think it is mistagged: Grego *is* using C++.

Comment: @kmkaplan Yes I see now. I'll retag it then.

Comment: kmkaplan thanks for the great explanation, that's what I wanted, you deserved the 100 reputation xD